# Theme Development -> Specific Homepage

Tags: theme-development, themes, homepage, frontpage

I am a beginner to starting a Wordpress template from scratch, so I am open to any helpful links or help that can be given to me :)

Questions:

- What would this file be called front-page or home.php?
- How could I make it so that both quotes are edited via the specific set page in the admin area?

I have the following HTML Code:

```
        <div class="quote"> 
            <h4>"If you've got the right lawyer with you, we've got the best justice system in the world"</h4> 
            <h4 id="author">Robert Trott - Justice</h4> 
        </div> 
    </div> <!-- end of header --> 

    <div id="nav"> 
        <div class="grid_4_home hoverable"> 
            <a href="index.html"><h3>Home <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
        </div> 

        <div class="grid_4 hoverable"> 
            <a href="expertise.html"><h3>My Expertise <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
        </div> 

        <div class="grid_4_about hoverable"> 
            <a href="about.html"><h3>About Us <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
        </div> 

        <div class="grid_4 hoverable"> 
            <a href="testimonials.html"><h3>Testimonials <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
        </div> 

        <div class="grid_4 hoverable"> 
            <a href="reports.html"><h3>Case Reports <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
        </div> 

        <div class="grid_4_last hoverable"> 
            <a href="contact.html"><h3>Contact Us <span class="lucida">&raquo;</span></h3></a> 
        </div> 
    </div> <!-- end of nav --> 

    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div><!-- end of wrap --> 

<div class="wrap IE7_fix"> 
    <div id="index_content" class="index"> 
        <div class="indexText"> 
                <h4>"I specialise in criminal defence and have done so for over ten years.  I have experience in all levels of criminal law from traffic law and minor offences to serious offences involving drugs, sexual violation, serious assaults or murder.</h4><br /> 
                <h4>I will listen to you and give you honest and confidential representation."</h4> 
        </div> 

        <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div> 

    <div id="footer"><small>Copyright &copy; 2011 John Munro</small></div> 

</div><!-- end of wrap -->
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to use the `front-page.php` template file. In WordPress parlance, **Home** refers to the **Blog Posts Index**, whether on the site front page or another static Page, and **Front Page** refers to the **Site Front Page**.

Second, you have several options for exposing a UI to manage your front-page quotes (in order of preference):

1. Make the Front Page a dynamic sidebar, with two Text Widgets, and a Menu Widget.
2. Create Theme Options for the two quotes
3. Add the quotes as custom post meta data to the static Page used as the Front Page
4. Make the quotes Custom Post Types, and pull them into `front-page.php`